# uiwebview not responding / pass touches to super

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, super, hittest, touches

So I wanted to make my UIWebview respon to touch events. I have read several topics about this. I created a Subclass of UIWebView, added it so my UIViewController and linked it via IB.
In my Subclass, i overrode touches ended and called [super touchedEnded]. didnt help.
I overrode hittest, but it doesnt call super either!

If I add this code to my subclassed UIWebView:

```
@implementation UIWebView (CustomView)

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

NSLog(@"hit");

return self;
    }

```
@end
```

then the touches ar forwarded to the superclass, but hittest is not(!)and additionally the webview stops scrolling.

Well, I want so recognize a touch in my webview and pass it to super  - what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I'm wondering, why so many suggestions include using 'hittest'  - this results in being unable to scroll your webview.....any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here - this is the version that did what I wanted: [The right way](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way). This is about subclassing UIWindow and passing on the events caught.

I would still love some explanations to my previous questions tho :P